# How to make my url as like as wordpress in my cakephp web application?

Tags: routes, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.6.7. I want to rewrite url as like as wordpress do. For example I have a url like: http://jegeachi.com/resellers/login. I want to see this url as http://jegeachi.com/resellers-login. I studied a lot and found some tips as routing. i.e: change config/routes.php as

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'resellers', 'action' => 'login'));
```

But I have lot controllers and every controller need such configurations. i.e: if I want to change url http://jegeachi.com/customers/login as http://jegeachi.com/customers-login. I need to change config/routes.php as

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'login'));
```

Is there any idea to generate such url for every controllers in cakephp.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in single routing configuration:

```
Router::connect('/:controller-:action');
```

If you would like to pass also other arguments to your action's method, then this one will be needed:

```
Router::connect('/:controller-:action/*');
```